# Cinemachine camera snaps on unpause

Tags: unity, cinemachine

In Unity, I am using a Cinemachine Freelook Camera with the Cinemachine Input Provider component. This follows around my character and overall responds correctly to 2-axis camera control.

However, when unpausing (setting Time.timeScale to 1 after it has been 0), the orbital camera will for a frame massively multiply the input of the camera control. This means that if the y axis control was 1, the orbital y value will effectively snap to 1 (instead of smoothly gliding there as it normally would).

I have determined it is not a case of buffered input in the paused state - it only considers the input at the moment of unpausing but unfortunately amplifies it.

**Is there anything I can do to prevent or at least counteract this effect?**

Note: The Cinemachine Brain updates on Fixed Update, and is not set to ignore time scale.